# Intermittent deserialization errors in REST WCF Service in .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, rest, exception

Since updating our project to Visual Studio 2012 and a targeting the .NET framework 4.5 from 4.0, we've been intermittently experiencing serialization exception issues when attempting to return data from our service methods, though for purposes of debugging the problem, we've focused our attention on a single service method, GetPageSelectListForSite.

This methods interface declaration is the following:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
UriTemplate = "/Pages/Site/ListItems/{siteId}",
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare),
Description("")]
IEnumerable<PageInfoItem> GetPreviousPages(string siteId);
```

It is called with the same signature parameter, and the same IEnumerable data is returned inside of a controller; however, occassionally (once every 100 or so times) this will result in a serialization exception when the controller is trying to deserialize the REST service reply:

*System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an error deserializing the object of type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Synodine.Hkd.Models.PageInfoItem, Synodine.Hkd.Models, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]. Encountered unexpected character 'D'. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Encountered unexpected character 'D'.*

The full exception and corresponding stack trace is available here:
http://pastebin.com/jaqQDbru

PageInfoItem is a fairly simple class containing a string, and derives from ListInfoBase which contains a guid, some strings, some bools, and a DateTime.

Attempts to decorate the classes with [Serializable] AND/OR [DataContract]/[DataMember] have not had any effect. We have not been able to consistently reproduce the problem.

I should note that we've seen the serialization exception error occur on an extremely simple REST GET method, with response/request formats set to Json and BodyStyle of Bare that returns a single string. It doesn't seem to matter if the rest service method in question is a POST/GET or whether its style is set to Bare or Wrapped, though in all cases we are making use of the WebMessageFormat.Json.

We've tried serializing the data ourselves and logging it to see if the JSON was malformed in some way, but the JSON is valid and is identical across failed/succeeded requests.

This was the code we used to serialize the data:

```
var stream1 = new MemoryStream();
var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(IEnumerable<PageInfoItem>));
ser.WriteObject(stream1, PageInfoItems);

stream1.Position = 0;
var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream1);
```

A sample of the JSON that is being logged is:

```
[
  {
    "DateLastUpdate": "\/Date(1362438368000+0000)\/",
    "DateLastUpdateString": null,
    "Id": "df2544e6-71a3-4f1c-ac54-d3c85269804f",
    "IsSelected": false,
    "Name": "samplepage",
    "Path": "\/samplepage"
  },
  <snip>
]
```

This problem only occurs in our deployed environments. All attempts to reproduce the problem on our local IIS webservers have failed.

We are using the WebChannelFactory to consume the WCF REST Services.  Because of this, we don't have (and are not sure how to get) direct access to the Response so we cannot be 100% of the data being sent across the wire.

Has anyone encountered anything similar to this when upgrading their projects to Visual Studio 2012/.NET 4.5 Framework?

Any responses definitely appreciated,
-- Shaun

Comment: This is what SO misses, a real problem and very well explained question. :)

Comment: How big is your returned data. Could size be the problem?

Comment: Thanks! It's fairly small, during our testing we made sure that the call was identical along with the data that is returned from the REST method, it's 1320 bytes after using DataContractJsonSerializer on it, assuming that the ChannelFactory is using the standard .NET DataContractJsonSerializer when converting it to JSON before passing it down the wire.

Comment: when one GET fails (e.g. /Pages/Site/ListItems/3), if you retry the same URL again, does it fail again?

Comment: That's the frustrating thing about it, refreshing against the same URL which hits the controller which calls the exact same service method with the exact same set of data will succeed the next time around.

Comment: and if we assume that for the same parameter (siteId=3), the GetPreviousPages returns the same result, then atleast 'data' issue can be ruled out.

Comment: Couple of more things: can you identify some pattern? e.g. you mentioned there are some other methods also which have failed. Are all of those methods returning IEnumerable? Can you try returning Array or List<T>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try exposing another function which return same data that GetPreviousPage returns, but changing the ResponseFormat to say Xml? Then call it multiple times (e.g. from a browser) and see if this new function *ever* fails. This well help you know if the problem is with Json Serializer.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
UriTemplate = "/Pages/Site/ListItemsNew/{siteId}",
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare),
Description("")]
IEnumerable<PageInfoItem> GetPreviousPagesNew(string siteId);
```

PS: Posted this as an answer as it's difficult to post code in comment.

Comment: Hey publicgk, Xml seemed to fix the problem, unfortunately, reworking all the REST service methods to XML would involve a major rewrite. EDIT: The server was way behind in terms of updates and service packs. After we updated, the problem went away. Lesson learned. Thanks for providing assistance, definitely appreciate it!